# Desktop shortcut for terminal command

Tags: gnome-terminal, shortcuts, .desktop

I was wondering how to make a clickable terminal shortcut for my desktop using the command `easytether connect`.

I don't want to have to open/close the terminal every time I wish to connect to the Internet through my phone.

I've tried updating my gnome-panel but I can only make a new directory on my desktop.

Comment: do you mean create Terminal Shortcut on desktop or embed terminal on desktop?

Comment: Please make it clearer to us what is the problem and what you want.

Comment: BTW, you may like Guake terminal. It's Quake-like terminal which appears/disappears with F12 (or any other) key. Personally, I use it a lot if I need to install some package or execute some useful alias.

Answer (score 34):

Right click the desktop and create an empty file (or use gedit) named `easytether.desktop`. Paste this into this file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Easytether
Exec=easytether connect
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

and save! You will then need to make the file executable, by editing the properties of the file, or running: `chmod +x easytether.desktop`.

- The `Name=Easytether` line specifies the name of the shortcut that will appear to the user.
- The `Exec=easytether connect` line specifies the command to be run, in this case, `easytether connect`.
- The `Terminal=true` line specifies that the command should be run in GNOME Terminal, so that the user can inspect its output. You can later set this to false if you don't want the shortcut to open a Terminal window. For instance, if you made a shortcut to the "sound" panel of the "settings" and want it to only open that (the command would be "gnome-control-center sound").
- You can even add a line `Icon=path/to/png/` (or `Icon=iconname` and put your `iconname.png` in `~.local/share/icons`) in order to add a custom icon to your launcher.

Also, you can put the `easytether.desktop` file into `~/.local/share/applications` and start it from Dash or other app-launcher (Synapse, Kickoff, Slingshot etc).

Comment: it worked thx!! ubuntu 12.10, btw, if you want to drag/drop at cairo-dock, it will fail but the cairo dock launcher has a gui to edit its fields so it is not a big problem :)

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 6):

I found this worked best for me, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

First, create a blank file on the desktop, name it Terminal.desktop (or anything-you-want.desktop)

Open the file with your preferred text editor (gedit, vim, nano, etc.) and paste/type-out the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.99
Name=Terminal
Comment=Terminal Desktop Shortcut
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/terminal-tango.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application
```

Save and quit.

I know I know, the icon doesn't look right yet, don't worry! Right click the file, select **Properties**, go to the **Permissions** tab, and tick 'Allow executing file as program'.

> *Alternatively, you can use **`chmod 775 Terminal.desktop`**
>   or **`chmod +x Terminal.desktop`** to give it execute permissions
>   using the terminal if you prefer terminal commands (when you are in
>   ~/Desktop).*

N' ta-da! That's all, really simple, looks pretty and works well too :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, that is also useful in other platforms, would be:

- Right click->Create new document->Empty document
- Call it howeverYouWant.sh
- Open it, and edit it writing in each line each line you'd use in the terminal, ergo: "easytether connect"
- Right click it->Properties->Permissions->Allow executing
- Double click the file, and choose Run in terminal

Answer (score 2):

Right click desktop and choose create Launcher.

Enter this in the command:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
```

Save it with a name and icon of your choice, and do NOT select "Run in terminal"

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to efaj, whose answer got me halfway there. For those who are still stumped, this should get you over the finish line:

1. Create an empty document, probably on the desktop, called *something*.sh (change the italicized part to whatever you want, but make sure the extension is .sh).
2. Edit the document and enter a series of terminal commands, one on each line, to accomplish your task. It's likely you'll want the first line to be a "cd" command that changes the active directory in the terminal session that will be launched.
3. Double-click the new document file.

   - If it launches, you're all done.
   - If you get a dialog that asks if you want to run the file or display its contents, choose the "Run in Terminal" option.
   - If the file opens in an editor, or you want to always run .sh files but you got the dialog mentioned above, open Nautilus (a.k.a. Files) and choose "Edit-Preferences" from the menu, then click the "Behavior" tab. In the "Executable Text Files" section, you can choose whether to run .sh (and other executable text type) files, view them, or ask what to do when you launch them.

Answer (score 0):

Fought this for way to long before seeing this..............

"open Nautilus (a.k.a. Files) and choose "Edit-Preferences" from the menu, then click the "Behavior" tab. In the "Executable Text Files" section, you can choose whether to run .sh (and other executable text type) files, view them, or ask what to do when you launch them."

problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Click on "Search your computer and ressources" on the left toolbar (launcher). In the bottom, click applications. In "Installed", search the Terminal you want to use, open it.

The application appear on the left toolbar, right click and select "lock to Launcher".